Elasticsearch SQL query for like and not in
I need to write a SQL query for elasticsearch SQL access engine. The query is show tables like %search_text% and table not in(schema)---here schema is string that contains comma separated database names.
It seems that elasticsearch does not support in/not in and such. Does anyone know a workaround for this.
I tried using rlike as I learned that might be a suitable solution but that also gives a parsing exception.
My existing query for filtering table based only on LIKE clause is--SHOW TABLES LIKE '%{schema_name}%'. This works fine. I need to add clause for not in (schema) here, and that is where I need help

Why have you tagged SQL server?
